# Creating a flexible API class in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm trying to design an API helper function for an app. The idea is that I'll be able to call the function from a viewController, using code such as:

```
let api = APIController();
api.request("get_product_list")
api.delegate = self
```

Here's the class so far:

```
import Foundation

protocol APIControllerProtocol {
 func didReceiveAPIResults(originalRequest: String, status: Bool, data: String, message: String)
}


class APIController { 

 var delegate: APIControllerProtocol?

 let url = "https://example.co.uk/api.php"
 let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
 let appID = "EXAMPLEAPPID";
 let deviceID = "EXAMPLEDEVICE"

 func request(req:String)-> Void {
    let urlString = "\(url)?request=\(req)"
    let combinedUrl = NSURL(string: urlString)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: combinedUrl!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let stringPost="app_id=\(appID)&device_id=\(deviceID)"
    let data = stringPost.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    request.timeoutInterval = 60
    request.HTTPBody=data
    request.HTTPShouldHandleCookies=false

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in
        do {
            let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as! NSDictionary
            let statusInt = jsonData["status"]! as! Int
            let status = (statusInt == 1)
            let data = String(jsonData["data"])
            let message = String(jsonData["message"])
            self.delegate?.didReceiveAPIResults(req,status: status,data: data,message: message)
        } catch _ {
            print("ERROR")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
 }
}
```

The difficulty I'm having is that the 'data' parameter might one of the following:

1. A string / number, such as the number of purchases a customer has made
2. An array of items, such as a list of products
3. A dictionary, such as the customer's details

I've set the data parameter to String as that allowed me to do some testing, but then converting it back into something usable for a tableView got very messy.

Are there any experts on here that can advise me the best way to do this? Perhaps showing me how I'd use the results in a cellForRowAtIndexPath method? Here's an example response from the API, in case it's useful:

```
{
"status":1,
"message":"",
"cached":0,
"generated":1447789113,
"data":[
    {"product":"Pear","price":0.6},
    {"product":"Apple","price":0.7},
    {"product":"Raspberry","price":1.1}
]
}
```

Comment: Since you know that it can only be one of three types, I would create three class methods that each return one specific type. I would cast to a type inside the method that fetches the data. It is the logical place for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One function doing too many things at once makes a really messy code. Also you don't want too many `if` statements or `enums` - your View controller will grow really fast.

Id suggest splitting request and parse logic. Your API class would be then responsible **only** for requests. It would return data to another class, that would be responsible for parsing. Then in the Parser class you could add methods like `toDictionary()` or `toArray()`, `toArrayOfClasses()` and so on. That would be the basic API structure.

If you want to expand it a little bit, you could add another class layer that would handle all that logic so your View Controller doesn't know if it uses API or another data source - this way you could easy implement new things in the future, like Core Data or migrate from your API class to some framework, maybe Parse.com - this layer gives you flexibility.

**Example structure:**

1. API - requests
2. Parser - parsing API response
3. DataManager - Send request to API and return parsed response.

*or* if you don't want this third point, you can just request & parse in the view controller.